# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'arr' was corrupted. occurred

Tags: c

I'm pretty new to coding so im not sure why im getting this error on visual studios. The adjust array function is at the bottom

```
int main() 
{

    int arr[7] = { 75,23,58,75,31,46,75 };

    unsigned int i = 0;

    printf("Unadjusted Array\n ");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    printf("Adjusted Array\n");
    AdjustArray(arr, 7);
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", arr[i]);
        }
    return 0;
}
 void AdjustArray(int arr[], unsigned int size)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size ;i++)
    {
        arr[i]= 0;
        i++;
        arr[i] *= -1;
    }

}
```

`

Comment: Start by catching the error in the *debugger* to see when and where in your code it happens, and check the values of all involved variables at that point (especially variables you use as array indexes).

Comment: If you want more help from us you need to create a [mcve] to show us, and preferably tell us where in the code you have the problem. Also please read about (or refresh) [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Can you show the function `AdjustArray`, which you are using in `main`?

Comment: Showing the implementation of `AdjustArray` would be more useful than the unused `GetBinomialCoefficient` don't you think?

Comment: my bad copied the wrong one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `AdjustArray` you are incrementing `i` inside the loop.

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size ;i++)
{
    arr[i]= 0;
    i++;
    arr[i] *= -1;
}
```

In the last loop, `i==6` if will pass the condition `i<size` but the line `i++` will make the value of `i` as 7. This is outside the array size and is giving you the error.